# How can I get the list of input sources shown when switching between input sources?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, keybindings, input-source

I cannot get it to show on another MacBook.

I'm expecting the list to be shown when I press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that often conflicts exist between the shortcuts used for changing Input Sources and those used for showing the Spotlight search field.

To check/change these, follow these steps:

1. Go to Apple > System Preferences
2. Select the Keyboard preference pane
3. Select the Shortcuts tab
4. In the list at left, if you notice a warning icon next to either or both the Spotlight and Input Sources options, then you know you've got a conflict. If so,

   - you can select Spotlight on the left to remove the ticks from the checkboxes, or
   - you can set new shortcuts by clicking the current shortcut and then pressing the new key combination you want to use.

**Note:** Obviously you can change either or both sets of shortcuts to suit your needs, and you may need to do this on either or both Macs.

Comment: Thank you, but the switch itself works, just without the list shown.
While the good news is that I got the list appeared after reboot. the bad news is that I probably will never found the reason...